# When constrain violation exception occures

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, transactions

I use jdbc with autocommit off. And I have a table with unique index. Is it possible that constraint violation exception occurres on Connection#commit and not on PreparetStatement#execute.

In my case (Oracle) it always occurres on 'execute'. 
Does it depend on database?

Comment: A strange question. What exactly you need to know? On execute when changes are executed on DB side the exception happens. That's correct. In case of batch update it might happen later (when all the changes set is sent to DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally constraints are evaluated when you execute the command and not at commit.

But SQL has a feature to define constraints as *DEFERRABLE*: Then the integrity check can be deferred to the point when the transaction is completed.

In Oracle this behaviour can be achieved with the [DEFERRABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) clause in the constraint definition and the [SET CONSTRAINTS DEFERRED](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10003.htm) command.

Comment: Nitpick : if a constraint is declared DEFERRABLE, then it is just that, deferrable, i.e. it is ***possible*** to have them checked at commit time, but it might still be the case that it is checked immediately (if the declaration does not include INITIALLY DEFERRED or some such).

Comment: @ErwinSmout you are right, changed wording to express the ability